# Ongoing kernel panics on Mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, kernel-panic

I've been having an ongoing issue with Kernel panics on my mid-2014 MacBook Pro running Big Sur, 11.7.3. Log from the latest is below. Things I have tried:

- Full system reformat and reinstall
- memtest86 (4 passes, no memory errors)
- Boot into Apple Diagnostics (No issues found)
- Switching to regular use of Firefox instead of Chrome

Issues *seem* to happen most often in the web browser, and after waking/login.

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0a
 family: 6 model: 70 stepping: 1 microcode: 28
 signature: 0x40661
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
 10 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xbe00000000800400
 IA32_MC4_ADDR(0x412):   0x00007fff204fdd86
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x00007fff204fdd86
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 6, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 29584139 loops in 1396766742 ticks
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff800f9c21d9): "Machine Check at 0xffffff800f9b559a, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000010a7ed000, CR3: 0x000000022b5fc1a0, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000018, RDX: 0x0000000000000001\n" "RSP: 0xffffffa0b0be3938, RBP: 0xffffffa0b0be3960, RSI: 0x0000000000000018, RDI: 0x00007fff302b5490\n" "R8:  0xffffffa0b0be3da0, R9:  0x00007fff302b5490, R10: 0x0000000000000100, R11: 0x0000000000000000\n" "R12: 0xffffff869d0892a0, R13: 0xffffffa0b0be3da0, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffffa0b0be39e8\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000282, RIP: 0xffffff800f9b559a, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/90c5b03f75/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.141.49/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff800f7592d0 : 0xffffff800f88822d 
0xffffff800f759320 : 0xffffff800f9d0be3 
0xffffff800f759360 : 0xffffff800f9c11da 
0xffffff800f7593b0 : 0xffffff800f82ca2f 
0xffffff800f7593d0 : 0xffffff800f887a4d 
0xffffff800f7594f0 : 0xffffff800f887d43 
0xffffff800f759560 : 0xffffff801009bcea 
0xffffff800f7595d0 : 0xffffff800f9c21d9 
0xffffff800f7596c0 : 0xffffff801009fa8e 
0xffffff800f7596d0 : 0xffffff800f82d28f 
0xffffffa0b0be3960 : 0xffffff800fb0c10b 
0xffffffa0b0be3b80 : 0xffffff800fb28bf9 
0xffffffa0b0be3be0 : 0xffffff800fb2ed3e 
0xffffffa0b0be3f20 : 0xffffff800fb2f644 
0xffffffa0b0be3f40 : 0xffffff800ff3d01e 
0xffffffa0b0be3fa0 : 0xffffff800f82d1f6 

Process name corresponding to current thread: plugin-container

Mac OS version:
20G1116

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Fri Dec 16 00:35:00 PST 2022; root:xnu-7195.141.49~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 5C6437D0-3E72-3CE6-A06A-A14A999AF7ED
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000f600000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800f800000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000f610000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800f810000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f700000
System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 35770315737096
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000020886cf6eefb
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000001b1bc7236e 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 35687094696867: >!AHIDKeyboard 224 (addr 0xffffff8010d3f000, size 16384)
last stopped kext at 228356001284: >IOPlatformPluginLegacy  1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7faa7a8000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.6.2
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   122.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 16.0.5
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.3.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.3.6
>eficheck   1
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.5d7
>!ASMCLMU   212
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    16.0.5
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.5d7
|SCSITaskUserClient 436.140.1
>!UTCKeyEventDriver 256
>!UTCButtons    256
>!UTCKeyboard   256
>!UCardReader   511.141.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.12
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.141.3
>!AAHCIPort 346.100.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AHIDKeyboard  224
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.5d7
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  6.3.6
|IOSerial!F 11
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAVB!F    940.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  585.2
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGPUWrangler  6.3.6
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.3.6
|IOGraphics!F   585.2
>!UAudio    405.39
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    985.2
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.5d7
>!UMultitouch   264
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.8.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
|IOAHCI!F   294.100.1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   985.2
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.5d7
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.5d7
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.141.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.140.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.140.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.140.1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: From the log, it says that a panic occurred on  CPU 6; it’s one of your CPU cores. This points to hardware.  It’s not necessarily the CPU, but maybe the cache, the I/O to/from the CPU, etc.  This needs to go in for service.

Comment: @Allan Thanks, but is it worth bringing in a mid-2014 MBP for service? What are they going to do for me?

The CPU with the issue in these logs changes each time, btw.

Comment: It’s tough to say.  Depending on the shop\tech, they may fix your logic board or they may replace it.  Depending on the cost, it might make sense. Then again, a new MacBook Pro is never a bad thing. It’s always good to know what your options are.

Answer (score 1):

This particular kernel panic is a machine check exception, which indicates that some type of error condition was detected by the CPU itself.

The comment I saw about the panic occurring on cpu 6 as being indicative of a problem with the CPU is not really the correct way of interpreting the panic. All kernel panics (by the nature of things) happen on a CPU. It doesn't mean that the kernel panic is caused by or related to the CPU at all.

However, in your specific case the kernel panic is, as mentioned, a machine check exception. The kernel panic contains the values of various registers from which it is possible to decode the cause of the MCE (machine check exception). In this case it is an "Invalid timer error".

The status registers also indicate that it could be possible to continue executing after this MCE. I.e. some error conditions are temporary in nature, and the system could keep running just fine after such an MCE.

The operating system has tried to progress, but it has timed out waiting for CPU core number 6 to finish flushing its translation lookaside buffer (table for mapping from virtual memory addresses to physical memory addresses).

From the kernel panic it looks like you're running software that could be  using virtualization (i.e. it is containerized software). You are also on relatively old hardware. The timeout value is set to some value that is deemed "reasonable" on a modern Mac - but for an old computer, and especially one that is doing virtualization work loads, it might be set a bit too low.

You can try disabling the timeout and essentially make the system wait as long as it takes for the CPU core to finish its work. You can do that by adding:

```
tlbto_us=0
```

to the `boot-args` of your system. Another possibility is to also add:

```
vti=9
```

to the `boot-args`. This changes various timeouts within the operating system to better suit a virtualization work load.

This small configuration change might solve your problem entirely - or it might just make your computer hang/freeze instead of kernel panic.

As it is very likely that this problem is hardware related, I would suggest to make sure the CPU is properly cooled. An older machine could have a malfunctioning CPU fan(s) - i.e. either worn out/damaged, or filled with dust. Make sure the computer internals are as dust free as possible and that the fans are working properly.

If that is still not helpful, there is a slight chance that you could fix the problem by replacing RAM modules. If not, then it is either the CPU that needs replacement or the main board itself. For a 2014 MacBook Pro that essentially means that getting a different computer - it is usually not worth it considering that a used 2014 MBP can be purchased at very low cost.

Comment: Wow thanks for all this. What tells you that I am running virtualization software? I previously used Parallels with my Boot camp partition but I have not installed it since reformatting.

Comment: It was just a "guess" based on the observed error - virtualization software means more TLB flushes. Note that some software uses virtualization "under the hood", so you might be doing virtualization even if you're not running Parallels or VMware. If you're not, then don't use the "vti=9" advice, but try the "tlbto_us=0" trick. I have a feeling you might be using Firefox a lot - you could try running without Firefox for a while to see if it helps anything.